# javascript enable disable radio button on click and select only one at a time

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, toggle

I am trying to do this.

I have 3 radio buttons,

1. If click on a radio and it's set, next time i click on it. It should
   be unchecked/rest.

I want to do in standard javascript without jquery as can't have that at the moment.

Here's my code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>  
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">

  <script type="text/javascript">

   function toggle(radioBtn)
   {
     if(radioBtn.checked)
     {
       radioBtn.checked = false;
     }
     else
     {
      radioBtn.checked = true;
     }


     // only select one at a time.

   }

  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <form id="myForm" name="myForm">
  <input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="radioBtn1"    value="A" onClick="toggle(this);" />
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="radioBtn1"    value="B" onClick="toggle(this);"/>
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="radioBtn1"    value="C" onClick="toggle(this);"/>
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Please help. Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Radio buttons that share the same "name" attribute will be managed by the browser such that it is not possible for more than one to be set. I don't see why you need code to do that at all, in other words.

Comment: @Pointy, Thanks. You are right now I want the other part. toggling the radio button. How can I do that.

Comment: You cant set more than one radio button. You must use checkbox.

Comment: Not really relevant but it's invalid for all your radio buttons to have the same "id" value like that.

Comment: The problem is that the browser sets the "checked" flag *before* it calls your event handler.  Thus when you click an un-checked button, the "checked" flag is already set to `true` so your handler turns it back off.

Comment: @Pointy. I can change the "id"s no problem. How all i want is how can i toggle the radio button to unchecked/checked stat etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just do something simple and straight forward inline, like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="radioBtn1" value="A" onMouseDown="this.__chk = this.checked" onClick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false" />
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="radioBtn2" value="B" onMouseDown="this.__chk = this.checked" onClick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false"/>
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="radioBtn3" value="C" onMouseDown="this.__chk = this.checked" onClick="if (this.__chk) this.checked = false"/>
```

Comment: onMouseDown="this.__chk  what is this __chk?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a record of which radioButton is checked and which isn't (can be done with hidden fields or an array) and set the checked/unchecked accordinally

Answer (score 0):

You can get around the browser's default behavior for radio buttons and achieve the toggle effect you're after by creating an additional 'hidden' radio button, and simulating a `click` event for it when the user toggles off one of the visible buttons. See a working example in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k73Nt/

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a solution which will go into the book for being clean but i got it working.

http://jsfiddle.net/C9At9/3/

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="radioBtn1" value="A" onmouseup="toggle(this);"/>
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="radioBtn2" value="A" onmouseup="toggle(this);" />
<input type="radio" name="radioBtn" id="radioBtn3" value="A" onmouseup="toggle(this);"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function toggle(radioBtn)
 {   
   if(radioBtn.checked)
   {
     setTimeout("disableRadio('"+radioBtn.id+"')",10);
   } else {
     radioBtn.checked = true;
   }
 }

function disableRadio(radioId) {
    el = window.document.getElementById(radioId);
    el.checked = false;
}
```

Your code wasn't working because the javascript setter gets overruled by html click events or something. I don't know how to explain it the correct way but having a delay solves your problem.

Hope this helps out!